# When I run the query in query analyzer, it returns one row but when I use the same query in VB.NET, no rows are returned

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

Here is the code:

```
 Function getData(ByVal id As String)
    Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim statement As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer

    statement = "SELECT * FROM General WHERE accountid='" + id + "'"
    Conn.Open()
    Comm = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(statement, Conn)
    reader = Comm.ExecuteReader()
    count = reader.FieldCount

    Dim Data(count) As String
    If reader.HasRows Then

        For temp = 0 To count
            Data(temp) = (reader.Item(temp))
        Next temp
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
    End If

    reader.Close()
    Conn.Close()

    Return Data
End Function
```

When I run the code the `HasRows` field is true but `reader.Item(temp)` gives the error

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: Not addressing the question, but you shouldn't be doing DB access this way - concatenating in the id like that leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot problem solved...
@David Hall then how should i access DB pls advise

Comment: do some research into SqlClient, SQL Inection and parameters. Have a look at this post, which is the first google hit for the terms I mentioned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `While reader.Read()` loop.  The reader starts at row index -1; the Read() will advance to the first row (well, fetch it) and then you can process it.

That's why your HasRows returns true but you can't retrieve the fields -- you're not positioned at the first row yet.

You may want to do something like this:

```
If reader.HasRows Then
  While reader.Read()
    For temp = 0 To count
        Data(temp) = (reader.Item(temp))
    Next temp
  End While
Else
    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
End If
```